# Find same address with different spelling (Like abbreviation) with sql

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-replace

I want to find same address with different spelling/expression (abbreviation) example like below. But my query is not working. For example St-->Street(correct) but Street-->Streetict.
Here is the code.

```
SELECT B_ADDRESS,H_ADDRESS, REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(B_ADDRESS,'S[a-z]r.|(St.)','Street'),'(Dist.)|(Dt.)','Street') as B_NEW,
        REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(H_ADDRESS,'(Str.)|(St.)','Street'), '(Dist.)|(Dt.)','District') as H_NEW
        FROM (

 SELECT H_ADDRESS,B_ADDRESS
                FROM
                ( 
                    SELECT 'Washington Str. No:60 ABD' AS H_ADDRESS,'Washington Street No60 ABD' AS B_ADDRESS FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
                    SELECT 'Pennsylvania Dt. St. No 6 ABD' AS H_ADDRESS,'Pennslyvania District Street No6 ABD' AS B_ADDRESS FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'Onion Dist.  No 63 Kartal' AS H_ADDRESS,'Onion District No 61 Kartal' AS B_ADDRESS FROM DUAL
                )
                )
```

---

Thanks for helping.I wrote that code as below and It is working.

```
 SELECT B_ADDRESS,H_ADDRESS,B_ADDRESS_C,H_ADDRESS_C,
 UTL_MATCH.jaro_winkler_similarity(B_ADDRESS_C,H_ADDRESS_C) AS JWS,
 UTL_MATCH.jaro_winkler(B_ADDRESS_C,H_ADDRESS_C) AS JW,
 UTL_MATCH.edit_distance_similarity(B_ADDRESS_C,H_ADDRESS_C) AS EDS,
 UTL_MATCH.edit_distance(B_ADDRESS_C,H_ADDRESS_C) AS ED

 FROM (

 SELECT H_ADDRESS,B_ADDRESS,
 INITCAP(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(H_ADDRESS,'S[a- 
 zA-Z]{1,}|S[a-zA-Z]r|S[t]','Street'),'D[a-zA-Z]{1,}|D[a-zA-Z] 
 {1,}|D[a-zA-Z]','District'),'[.: ]',' ')) AS H_ADDRESS_C,
 INITCAP(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(B_ADDRESS,'S[a- 
 zA-Z]{1,}|S[a-zA-Z]r|S[t]','Street'),'D[a-zA-Z]{1,}|D[a-zA-Z] 
 {1,}|D[a-zA-Z]','District'),'[.: ]',' '))  AS B_ADDRESS_C


            FROM
            ( 
                SELECT 'Washington Str. No:60 ABD' AS 
 H_ADDRESS,'Washington Street No60 ABD' AS B_ADDRESS FROM DUAL UNION 
 ALL 
                SELECT 'Pennslyvania Dt. St. No 6 ABD' AS 
 H_ADDRESS,'Pennslyvania District Street No6 ABD' AS B_ADDRESS FROM 
 DUAL UNION ALL
                SELECT 'Onion Dist. No 63 Kartal' AS H_ADDRESS,'Onion 
 District No 61 Kartal' AS B_ADDRESS FROM DUAL
            )
            )
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you're looking for *similar* addresses. How similar, is up to you to decide.

With sample data:

```
SQL> select * from test;

H_ADDRESS                     B_ADDRESS
----------------------------- ------------------------------------
Washington Str. No:60 ABD     Washington Street No60 ABD
Pennsylvania Dt. St. No 6 ABD Pennslyvania District Street No6 ABD
Onion Dist.  No 63 Kartal     Onion District No 61 Kartal
```

you can use `utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity` which says how similar (in percentage) are two values. It returns

```
SQL> select h_address, b_address,
  2    utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(h_address, b_address) sim
  3  from test;

H_ADDRESS                     B_ADDRESS                                   SIM
----------------------------- ------------------------------------ ----------
Washington Str. No:60 ABD     Washington Street No60 ABD                   96
Pennsylvania Dt. St. No 6 ABD Pennslyvania District Street No6 ABD         88
Onion Dist.  No 63 Kartal     Onion District No 61 Kartal                  89

SQL>
```

Now, as I said, is up to you to decide which similarity is good enough for you. Is it 80%? 90%? 95%? I can't tell, you decide. When you do, use it as

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select h_address, b_address,
  3       utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(h_address, b_address) sim
  4     from test
  5    )
  6  select h_address, b_address
  7  from temp
  8  where sim >= 90;           --> here

H_ADDRESS                     B_ADDRESS
----------------------------- ------------------------------------
Washington Str. No:60 ABD     Washington Street No60 ABD

SQL>
```

Or, have it all (addresses and similarity) as the result and let someone else do the comparison and filtering.

Comment: Thanks for helping.  I'm really greatful and it is really admirable. These functions working as well. Now ı will edit my question and answer now.